# C++ Segmentation fault if try-catch is introduced

Tags: c++, boost, try-catch

I am running the simplest interprocess communication program setup using `boost::interprocess`:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstdlib> //system
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::interprocess;
typedef pair<double, int> MyType;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc==1) {  //Parent process

        struct shm_remove {
            shm_remove() {shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
            ~shm_remove() {shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
        } remover;

        managed_shared_memory segment(create_only,"MySharedMemory",65536);
        MyType* instance=segment.construct<MyType>("MyType instance")(0.5,2);
        string s(argv[0]);
        s+=" child ";
        if(system(s.c_str())!=0) {
            cout<<"Parent: Child process returned non-zero"<<endl;
            return 1;
        }
        cout<<"Parent: Child process finished successfully"<<endl;
        segment.destroy<MyType>("MyType instance");

    } else { //Child process

        pair<MyType*, managed_shared_memory::size_type> res;
//        try {
            managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
            res=segment.find<MyType>("MyType instance");
//        } catch (interprocess_exception &e) {
//            cerr<<"Error while opening the segment"<<endl;
//            return 1;
//        }
        cout<<"Child: Segment of length "<<res.second<<" is found at "<<res.first<<endl;
        cout<<"Child: "<<res.first->first<<", "<<res.first->second<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works, and I see:

```
Child: Segment of length 1 is found at 0x106a15148
Child: 0.5, 2
Parent: Child process finished successfully
```

However, when I uncomment the `try-catch` block, I see the following:

```
Child: Segment of length 1 is found at 0x10a8fd148
Parent: Child process returned non-zero
```

If I break the binary into two (segment-generating and forever-sleeping parent and segment-reading child), it again works without `try-cacth`, but with it the child crashes with

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. What does the introduction of the `try-catch` cause? It behaves, as if the block had its own address space. But why would it?
2. How to safely check for the presence of the needed segment and generate an error message it is not found?

**EDIT:**

I have changed the block to:

```
if (1) {
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
    res=segment.find<MyType>("MyType instance");
    cout<<"Child: Segment of length "<<res.second<<" is found at "<<res.first<<endl;
    cout<<"Child: "<<res.first->first<<", "<<res.first->second<<endl;
}
```

I am getting the same error:

```
Child: Segment of length 1 is found at 0x108c15148
Child: 0.5, 2
Child: Segment of length 1 is found at 0x108c15148
Parent: Child process returned non-zero
```

Therefore, the behavior is indeed caused by `{}`, presumably due to the destruction of `segment`. But why would it matter, if `res.first` is already populated with the correct pointer?

Comment: What does `segment` destructor do? It looks like it frees something you're trying to access later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the destructor of `managed_shared_memory` is called, but you continue to rely on state or allocation held by it after the try catch block.

```
managed_shared_memory segment;
```

Recall that destructors are always called at the end of a scope (basically any closing `}`), and this goes for try blocks as well.

If this was not the ``main` function, it would likely be better to let the exception escape to the caller (no try catch), or re-throw it (or another exception):

```
    try {
        managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
        res=segment.find<MyType>("MyType instance");
        cout<<"Child: Segment of length "<<res.second<<" is found at "<<res.first<<endl;
        cout<<"Child: "<<res.first->first<<", "<<res.first->second<<endl;

    } catch (interprocess_exception &e) {
        cerr<<"Error while opening the segment"<<endl;
        throw;
    }
```

Indeed, have a look at [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html)

> The most important services of a managed memory segment are:
>
> - Dynamic allocation of portions of a memory the segment.
> - Construction of C++ objects in the memory segment. These objects can be anonymous or we can associate a name to them.
> - Searching capabilities for named objects.
> - Customization of many features: memory allocation algorithm, index types or character types.
> - Atomic constructions and destructions so that if the segment is shared between two processes it's impossible to create two objects
>     associated with the same name, simplifying synchronization.

Comment: So, the role of `segment` is not just providing the correct pointer to the underlying array? Does the destructor remove the address itself from the process address space?